# Why am I getting an error at this point in my code?

Tags: c#, arrays

So I'm new to coding so excuse me if my way of explaining my problem doesn't make too much sense. But I'm trying to create a simple Mad Lib game and I decided to use arrays to store the user's input in, But unfortunately, I'm getting a bunch of errors.

I'm getting the errors under Color, Shape, Size, Tool and Random

```
Color = Console.ReadLine();

Shape = Console.ReadLine();

Size = Console.ReadLine();

Tool = Console.ReadLine();

Random = Console.ReadLine();
```

I'm also getting errors where I'm trying to add the array into my text.

like here:
See how I'm trying to add the array

```
||  <--- this is an arrow indicating to where im getting my error,                                         
\/                      this has noting to do with the code itself.   



Console.WriteLine("your hair is" + Color);
```

This is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] BodyParts = new String[5];
    BodyParts[0] = "Color";
    BodyParts[1] = "Shape";
    BodyParts[2] = "Size";
    BodyParts[4] = "Tool";
    BodyParts[5] = "Random"; 

    Console.WriteLine("your hair is" + Color);
    Color = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("your eyes are " + Shape);
    Shape = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("your nose is {size} ");
    Size = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("your head looks like a {tool} ");
    Tool = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("your {Body} looks like a {?} ");
    Random = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.ReadLine();     
}
```

Comment: You're trying to access `Color` before you set it, put `Color = Console.ReadLine();` **before** `Console.WriteLine("your hair is" + Color);`

Comment: `Color` and others might not be declared neither. It helps **a lot** seeing the error messages

Comment: Also "Im getting an error" isn't very helpful. You should [explain what error you're getting](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/)

Comment: `BodyParts[0] = "Color";` if you want to place the color inside `BodyParts[0]`, you'll need to use `BodyParts[0] = Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: Your code never reaches the point where you call ReadLine. You have declared an array with 5 elements. This means that you can store elements from index 0 to index 4. Trying to set an element at index 5 gives an exception. Index Out of Range. Notice how do you miss to set the element at index 3 in your code?

Comment: Your array has 5 positions, and arrays are accesd starting with 0, so the "Tool" should be `BodyParts[3]` and "Random" should be `BodyParts[4]`. Looks like you skipped one

Comment: @Cid thanks for your help. I tried BodyParts[0] = "Color"; and BodyParts[0] = Console.ReadLine(); and it worked with no errors, but when i ran the code i got this. Exception Unhandled  System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array. What exactly does this mean?

Comment: Read again the comment posted by @bradbury9

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create those strings.

You can just add var in front of each line

```
Console.Writeline("Your hair color is: ")
var Color = Console.ReadLine()
...
```

So program will know that you are creating new strings.
And after you have values on each of those strings you can populate the array

```
Bodyparts[0] = Color
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If that is all your code, you are missing the declaration of the variables named `Color`, `Shape`, `Size`, `Tool` and `Random`. A variable declaration looks like `your_type variable_name`. You did fine with `string[] BodyParts`, in that code `BodyParts` was declared as an array of strings `string[]`.

Change those lines into:

```
string Color = Console.ReadLine(); // Do note this line and the next order has changed
Console.WriteLine("your hair is" + Color);

string Shape = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("your eyes are " + Shape);

string Size = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine($"your nose is {size} "); // Do note the added "$" before the string

string Tool = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine($"your head looks like a {tool} ");
```

**Edit**: You probably wanted to make use of a Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, string> BodyParts = Dictionary<string, string>(); // We initialize a Dictionary
BodyParts.Add("Color", ""); // Add elements to the dictionary, we later assign the value of them with the .ReadLine
BodyParts.Add("Shape", "");

BodyParts["Color"] = Console.ReadLine(); // We assign whatever user typed to the 'Color' BodyPart
Console.WriteLine("your hair is" + BodyParts["Color"]);

BodyParts["Shape"] = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("your eyes are " + BodyParts["Shape"]);

// We can also loop all properties and show them

foreach (string key in BodyParts.Keys)
{
    string value = BodyParts[key];
    Console.WriteLine("The " + key + " is/are " + value);
}
```

Comment: first thanks so much for replying. But i have a question, why do i add  "$", what is its purpose?

Comment: Its a bit advanced, but it is called "string interpolation". Is a mechanism to mix string literals and variables. You can check [string interpolation search -Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=string+interpolation+%5Bc%23%5D)

Comment: Dictionary needs two types `Dictionary<string, string>`